# Why need to include connection file before every stored procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have a `php` file whereby it is calling some `stored procedures`.

```
include "../../commonFilesForAll/db.php";
$tagQueryQcWaiting = "CALL qcWaitingQuery()";
$tagQueryQcWaitingExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $tagQueryQcWaiting);
$qcWaiting = mysqli_num_rows($tagQueryQcWaitingExecute);

$tagQueryQcFailed = "CALL qcFailedQuery()";
$tagQueryQcFailedExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $tagQueryQcFailed);
$qcFailed = mysqli_num_rows($tagQueryQcFailedExecute);

$tagQueryQcAssigned = "CALL qcAssignedQuery()";
$tagQueryQcAssignedExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $tagQueryQcAssigned);
$qcAssigned = mysqli_num_rows($tagQueryQcAssignedExecute);
```

But when I gave the above way, it is not working. I have to include the connection file before every query as below in order for it to work as shown below

```
include "../../commonFilesForAll/db.php";
$tagQueryQcWaiting = "CALL qcWaitingQuery()";
$tagQueryQcWaitingExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $tagQueryQcWaiting);
$qcWaiting = mysqli_num_rows($tagQueryQcWaitingExecute);

include "../../commonFilesForAll/db.php";
$tagQueryQcFailed = "CALL qcFailedQuery()";
$tagQueryQcFailedExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $tagQueryQcFailed);
$qcFailed = mysqli_num_rows($tagQueryQcFailedExecute);

include "../../commonFilesForAll/db.php";  
$tagQueryQcAssigned = "CALL qcAssignedQuery()";
$tagQueryQcAssignedExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $tagQueryQcAssigned);
$qcAssigned = mysqli_num_rows($tagQueryQcAssignedExecute);
```

Sample of my stored procedure as below
`qcWaitingQuery`

```
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM plannertags WHERE (`status` = '0' OR `status` = '2') 
  AND currentStage = '12' 
  AND assignedTo = '0' 
  AND handoverStatus = '0' 
  AND failedStatus = '0' 
  ORDER BY deliveryDate ASC;
END
```

`qcFailedQuery`

```
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM plannertags t JOIN failedTable n on t.srNumber = n.plannerTagsSrNumber
  WHERE (t.status = 0 OR t.status = 2) 
  AND t.currentStage = '12' 
  AND t.assignedTo = '0' 
  AND t.handoverStatus = '0' 
  AND n.failedDepartment = '12' 
  AND n.status = '0' 
  AND n.latestTag='1' 
  ORDER BY t.deliveryDate ASC;
END
```

`qcAssignedQuery`

```
BEGIN
  SELECT *FROM plannertags t JOIN qctable n on t.srNumber = n.plannerTagsSrNumber
  WHERE (t.status = 0 OR t.status = 2) 
  AND t.currentStage = '12' 
  AND t.assignedTo = '12' 
  AND t.handoverStatus = '0' 
  AND n.failedStatus = '0' 
  AND n.qcHold != '1'
  ORDER BY t.deliveryDate ASC;
END
```

My `db.php` file as follows

```
$servername = "111.11.11.111";
$username = "111";
$password = "111111";
$database = "111";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Does anyone know why is it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open the connection each time. Your mistake is that you are calling a stored procedure but you are not fetchin all results. SPs have a hidden behaviour that they always return a result on top of what `SELECT` statements you have inside of them. This means that you have two results which you need to fetch properly otherwise you will get out of synch error.

After each call to stored procedure fetch the second result and it should work.

```
include "../../commonFilesForAll/db.php";
$tagQueryQcWaiting = "CALL qcWaitingQuery()";
$tagQueryQcWaitingExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $tagQueryQcWaiting);
$qcWaiting = mysqli_num_rows($tagQueryQcWaitingExecute);

mysqli_next_result($conn); // fetch the empty result of SP call
```

You would see the proper out of synch error if you had the mysqli configured properly. Your connection script is incorrect. You must always enable error reporting. Replace it with:

```
$servername = "111.11.11.111";
$username = "111";
$password = "111111";
$database = "111";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

Make sure to remove the `if` statement. You should also set the correct connection charset. [Please read the manual for more information.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: Thank you Dharman. The reason why I didn't give any error reporting is because of I don't want user see the errors. I think with the above error reporting, sometimes user will be able to see even the username and password

Comment: @Anu You are mixing two things together. Error reporting should always be fully enabled. However, when the site goes live then the setting `display_errors` should be switched off. See [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: okay. its clear now. I am trying to figure out where to set `display_errors` from the link you mentioned.